How to utilize GPU by using turtlesim tool in my nvidia jetson agx orin developer kit
I have installed ROS2 on my nvidia jetson agx orin developer kit. So, I want to utilize GPU, when turtlesim tool is running, but unable, is there any way to utilize GPU by turtlesim.

for what do you want to use the GPU?
